# print lines between two regex if string founded in lines in sed

Tags: sed

[similar this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128655/tile-logfile-into-pieces-and-search-for-errors)

i have this file

```
START1
1
2
END1
START2
error
1
2
END2
START3
1
2
END3
```

i want if `error` found; `sed` extract the whole piece and print it

for example out put is

```
START2
error
1
2
END2
```

because `error` found between `START2` and `END2`

how to solve it only with `sed` ?!?

Comment: "how to solve it only with sed ?!?" Don't. Use awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n ':a;/START/,/END/{/END/!{$!{N;ba;}};/error/p;}' inputfile
```

The idea is to keep adding the lines in the pattern space between the two specified addresses.  If the regex (string `error` in this case) is found, then print the block.  `-n` wouldn't print anything unless explicitly specified.

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
START2
error
1
2
END2
```

Comment: Please suggest what could be improved about the answer.  Simply downvoting and moving on would help little to understand that.

Comment: Other than the fact that the brach `:a` can be moved inside the range `'/START/,/END/{:a;/END/..` I cannot suggest any improvements. +1 for simple logic that is easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '
   $inside = 1 if /START/;
   push @lines, $_ if $inside;
   $error = 1 if /error/ and $inside;
   if (/END/) {
       print @lines if $error;
       undef @lines;
       $inside = 0;
       $error = 0;
   }
' file
```